# golang: client tls.Conn Close hook

Tags: go, network-programming

I am interacting with an http client API which accepts a [`*tls.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Conn). I cannot change the API. I want some code to be executed when the connection is closed, but I don't see a way to do this. If I create a struct which embeds a `*tls.Conn` and I "override" `Close()`, the API won't accept the struct because go only follows the sub-type is-a relationship with interfaces - `tls.Conn` is **not** an interface.

Is there any way to get around this - is there some standard hook I can use to be notified when the client connection is closed?

Comment: Are you constructing the `*tls.Conn` yourself? Or do you get it ready-made before you pass it on to the API?

Comment: Constructing myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [tls.Client](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Client) to construct the `*tls.Conn` then you can wrap the first argument to achieve your goal.

```
type CloseListener struct {
    net.Conn // embed the original conn
}

func (c *CloseListener) Close() error {
    err := c.Conn.Close()
    // ... do your stuff ...
    return err
}

conn := tls.Client(&CloseListener{c}, &tls.Config{ /* ... */ })
```

If you look at how [tls.Conn's Close](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/conn.go#L1190-L1224) is implemented you'll see that it should call your Close implementation unless there was some error.